# returning static pointer to local variable from function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, static

I've found this code [on web](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/examples/returnrefpointer.htm) as an example, but I think this is not correct. An address to automatic variable is returned and this is just coincidence that it might work sometimes:

returning a pointer to an destroyed local variable, which becomes invalid memory location, is *undefined behavior*.

My only little hesitancy is about the pointer being `static`, but I think this changes nothing as this is the variable that should be `static` not a pointer: local variable is going to be destroyed. Can you please confirm or deny?

```
double *& showNumber()
{
    double n = 1550.85;
    static double *v = &n;
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double sn = *showNumber();
    sn = *showNumber();
    //...
}
```

Comment: static persists for the entire duration of the program as soon as you initialize them so this should be okay for v, not for n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code to be well-defined, both `n` and `v` would need to be `static`.

Right now, the `*showNumber()` has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as it dereferences a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: only `n` should be static

Comment: v should also be static as intended use of this function is also to return a pointer I think

Comment: @bolov: Why is that (bearing in mind that `v` is returned by reference)?

Comment: I am tired, didn't see the return by reference. You are right

Answer (score 2):

Your code has still undefined behaviour because the value of the static pointer is invalid after exiting the function. The local variable refered to by the pointer will be destroyed.And any next time when the function will be called the address of this local variable can be different.

You could write your function the following way

```
double * showNumber()
{
    static double n = 1550.85;
    return &n;
}
```

In this case the returned pointer would contain the same valid value.

Comment: In C, the code static double* v = &n; would be illegal, because &n is not a compile-time constant. In C++, it is legal; the initialisation happens the first time the static variable is used, and only once. So even if you wrote *v = 1.0; _inside_ that function, it would probably crash on the second call.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables persist for the entire duration of the program as soon as you initialize them. You're all set for `v`, but **not** for `n`'s address.

Answer (score 0):

If pointer and it's variable both are static then only code will be OK. Otherwise local variable will anyway going to die.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of local or global, static variable will live till the end of program.
but it is recommenced that to use global when we return the value of that variable. because static local may get affected due to threads.